# Solution to : My USPS label print contain a “SAMPLE-DO NOT MAIL” watermark

Tags: print, usps, labels, watermark

I had the issue were i was unable to print the shipping label without the "**SAMPLE DO NOT MAIL**" Watermark.
After 2 days of research on the google and every possible doc i could read it finally payed off.
Here is the solution and path to the correct file that need to be edited in your magento cpannel.

The API containing "**Certify**" is their testing API and will print labels with the sample watermark. In order to generate actual labels, you must remove "Certify" from all of your Web Tools XML requests.

So for those who don't know were it is in **magento 1.9.3.2** go to:

> public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/USPS.php

Open the file `usps.php` with the edit tool in your cPanel, or with any editing tool such as notepad+ etc...
in usps.php Run a search command by pressing command+F and delete the word   "certify".
In my case i only had 2 results showing so i just delete them and save.
go back and create a new shipping label and voila !!!!

if this doesn't work for you email your issue to uspstechnicalsupport@mailps.custhelp.com 
They usually answer you within 1 or 2 ours but you need to email them 3 times because first 2 will be auto responded.